# Year function in oracle using case statements

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to extract a year using the following case statement in oracle but I am getting an invalid identifier error on the YEAR function. Anyone know where I might be going wrong or how can I extract a year based on the following?

```
YEAR(CASE when XYX = 'Hired - External'
 AND YZN = 'Hire' THEN  CURRENT_DATE END) AS P_YEAR
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a `year()` function...

Comment: what do you need to get? a number, a string? and what is CURRENT_DATE? if it's a column, or a variable, what is its type? and where did you find the YEAR function?

Comment: Year
2018
2017
2016
2015  I found year function on oracle docs.

Comment: @Aleksej - that *is* [an Oracle function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CURRENT_DATE.html#GUID-96795097-D6F0-4288-90E7-9D7C49B4F6E5) *8-)

Comment: is there any other function in oracle that I can use to accomplish the same?

Comment: @AlexPoole: ... ops .. I'm beginning to see mistakes even where there aren't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't have a `year` function; maybe you saw it under a different DBMS product.

You need [`extract`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html):

```
CASE when XYX = 'Hired - External' AND YZN = 'Hire'
  THEN extract(year from CURRENT_DATE) END AS P_YEAR
```

This seems slightly odd as it will give you the year today, in your session time zone, not any year associated with your data.

Comment: thanks that worked exactly like I expected. The Year Function is available in Oracle OBIEE , the analytics tool and I didn't realize it wont work on the database side. thanks much